# Is it possible and legal to republish an App Store app?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible and legal to remove an App Store app (I ALREADY OWN AND I PUBLISHED IT) and publish it fresh again with:
a) the same bundle id
b) different name/description and bundle identifier?

Comment: Is it legal to take someone's book, rip off their cover, put your own cover on it, and resell it as a new book?

Comment: check the timestamps. You hadn't edited in the "already own" bit until AFTER my comment.

Comment: I know, and then I told You to read it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many many apps in the app store have changed their Bundle Name (name under the icon) and app store name and description.  Sometimes with an app the behaves and/or looks very different.  For whether this is legal or allowed by Apple, you have to read the iOS standard agreement, and submit an app to Apple.  Customers may or may not appreciate this change.

You have to be the original submitter of an app to reuse a Bundle ID and submit it.